# Jest test is not running properly with react-navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I'm working with react-native 0.59 and I want to write my firsts tests for my app. So reading the react docs I just need to run the following command `yart test` which executes the following file:

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

This is the default file for test when you start your app with react-native. But when I run `yarn test` command the test is failing. The traceback is the following:

```
FAIL  __tests__/App-test.js
● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: (0 , _reactNavigation.createBottomTabNavigator) is not a function

  43 |
> 44 | const MainStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
     |                                                               ^
  45 |   Home: { screen: Home },
  46 |   Pets: { screen: Pets },
  47 |   Notifications: { screen: UserNotifications },

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/app-navigator.js:44:63)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/Reducers/navigation.js:2:44)
```

This is a part of my `app-navigator.js` file:

```
const PetStack = createStackNavigator({
  UpdatePet: { screen: UpdatePet },
}, {
  mode: 'card',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' }
  }
});

const MainStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Pets: { screen: Pets },
  Notifications: { screen: UserNotifications },
  UpdateUser: { screen: UpdateUser },
});
```

These are the failing lines. It's so weird because when I `console.log` the `createStackNavigator` it logs a mocked function, but when I do it with `createBottomTabNavigator` it logs `undefined`.

This is my jest configuration:

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native",
  "verbose": true,
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
  },
  "globals": {
    "NODE_ENV": "test"
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js"
  ],
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "src",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/(?!native-base|react-native-localize|react-navigation|react-navigation-redux-helpers)/"
  ],
  "setupFiles": [
    "./jest-setup.js"
  ]
}
```

I've reading some related issues and just found [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5742). They recommend set the key `inlineRequires` to `false` in `node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js` but it does not work for me

Comment: I have the same issue and cannot figure out how to fix it. Please update your post if you find a solution

Comment: I've not found any update, but reading it looks that there is no way to do it, you need to mock all entire navigation process @YanivShnaider

Comment: @GermanAlzate i am facing same issue . any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

create a file `jest.config.js` at the root of your project where `package.json` file is placed.

```
// jest.config.js
const {defaults} = require('jest-config');
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: [...defaults.moduleFileExtensions, 'ts', 'tsx'],
};
```

For more details, see [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1792)